# Passing configurations down the application layers

Tags: .net, logging, design-patterns, configuration, architecture

What's the best practices of passing configurations to the layer it utilizes?

For example, dealing with connection strings or app.settings in case of several services eventually reaching the same DAL. Or if I want to write to the same log file independently of the class that's calling it.

Is there any common practices/patterns of passing the name of connection string/log file name/etc. down the application layers?

Answer (score 0):

It could be different per environment/language, but in node.js it would be good to store things just under some kind of `app.config`. Good example is Sails.js framework (which is MVC framwework - Rails for Node.js) - All the configuration stored in global app object `sails` under `sails.config.<yourConfigKey>`.

Any config could be recieved from process environment variables, config files, remote configuration providers like Consul go there, and added as keys during load/bootstrap phase.